# What does "PDF-compatible glyph names" mean?

Tags: fonts, typography, pdf

In Fontographer 5, when I want to generate font files, it asks me do I want to "Keep glyph names as they are" or make glyph names "PDF-compatible".
What does the "PDF-compatible glyph name" mean really?
Do I need this for distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure on this, but I think the question [How to change PDF text encoding ? (ANSI to UNICODE)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8572/how-to-change-pdf-text-encoding-ansi-to-unicode) may illustrate one of the problems if you *don't* make the glyphs PDF-compatible.

Also, the Fontographer manual says you should, without clearly explaining why.